# How to kill all process on ssh logout? (Kill running Background proccess started with screen etc)

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen, nohup

Hi i have a multiuser centos server running. There are for example 3 users (non root) - each of them have their own homedir. 
SSH Login is allowed (bash).

How could it be reached, if a user started a background process with:

- screen
- nohup
- etc.

that this proccess  be killed if the user logout from ssh-shell or lost the internet connection? All root and processes from the other users should persist. 
Sorry for my bad english. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Very good answer is: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136552/32544

Comment: Thanks! i found this thread helped me for the executed pam_session.sh : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74063/kill-user-processess-on-logout But i edited the /etc/pam.d/sshd file.

Comment: ok the script works only if each ssh session of user is exiting. and a other problem with php-fpm is still there, if the user owns a pool they will killed too. From php-fpm errorlog: WARNING: [pool sshuser] child 22139 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 331.926225 seconds from start. Does anybody know a solution with cgroups ?